# Animating react-transition-group with ReactDOM createPortal

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, react-hooks, react-transition-group, react-animations

I have been breaking my head trying to figure out how to accomplish something that I figured would be quite simple (I know...)

Goal is for a very *minimal*, and *reusable* modal component that I can animate in some sort of HOC with a trigger button or w/e.

I am creating it using createPortal, and the goal is to have some simple animations be added to on enter/**exit** of said portal.

I have gotten this to work using GSAP, but ideally I would love for this to go along with SC instead so that I don't have to pull in another animation library.

For the life of me I just cannot get this to work with SC and would love if someone could point me in the right direction.

I have made a sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/r44w9m4o5p using GSAP to run the animations, and it's a bit hacky but it is in the proper direction for what I am going for.

Also, is there a benefit to using react-transition-group over something like https://github.com/react-tools/react-move?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `CSSTransition` component instead of `Transition`. `CSSTransition` will just toggle approriate class names using given animation timings: `.*-enter`, `.*-enter-active` for in-transition and `.*-exit`, `.*-exit-active` for out-transition. So you can define all transitions using CSS3 properties with `styled-components`.

Take a look at my fork: https://codesandbox.io/s/zz95v5103

I've just extended your `Modal` with transition styles. Note that extending styles [requires `className` property for the component to be extended](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#styling-any-components), so I've added that property to your `Modal` component.

Comment: Is there a reason for using `styled-components` rather than just using CSS/sass (apart from being able to inject the duration?)?

Comment: @Simon, you can use any styling method. There is no specific reason to use styled-components.